# Cordova installation exits without any error in Windows7

Tags: node.js, cordova, command-line-interface

My PC is Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit. And I downloaded the stable v5.5.0 NodeJS x64 installer. And I ran the Command Prompt by running it as Admin(by right clicking and choosing the `Run As Administrator` menu).

Then used the installation command:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

It shows some loading bar and when it reaches 25%, it exits the installation.

I have Kaspersky Internet Security installed on my PC. I tried pausing it and then ran again. Still no use. I found that the `npm-cache` folder is having some folders generated:

[image]

What is the issue and how can I successfully install Cordova in my PC?

Comment: Did you find any solution?Is it because of the windows version?

Comment: Nope. Still no hope.